# Main thread usage

Tags: android, performance, user-interface

I'm trying to determine what's degrading the performance of my app, and I'm looking into what's monopolizing the main thread.

I just discovered `Looper.setMessageLogging` and am setting a customer `Printer` to see how the main thread is being used:

```
Looper.getMainLooper().setMessageLogging(new LogPrinter(Log.DEBUG, "MainLooper")) {

    private long startTime = 0L;

    @Override
    public void println(String x) {
        if (x.startsWith(">")) {
            startTime = System.nanoTime();
        } else if (x.startsWith("<")) {
            final long duration = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
            x += " (" + (duration / 1000000L) + " ms)";
        }
        super.println(x);
    }

});
```

This has led me to discover that, yes, there is a lot of code taking more than 500 ms, and some taking almost a second, which is probably why the performance is so bad.

```
D/MainLooper( 1542): >>>>> Dispatching to Handler{433ae6a0} null: 1000
D/MainLooper( 1542): <<<<< Finished to    Handler{433ae6a0} null (952 ms)
```

Now, I'm left to make sense of those log messages however. I don't have any idea what method is taking 952 ms on the main thread. Is there a better way of pinpointing the method that is taking so long?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check out [THIS](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) article about using method profiling to determine where your app is running slow.

If you're using Eclipse: In the DDMS tab you will see a button in the Devices window that has some arrows and a red record icon on it. This is the "Start method profiling" button. Click this and start up your app and perform your actions that were causing slow downs. Once done, click that icon again to stop recording. Give it a few seconds to pull the results from your phone and it will show you a nice timeline showing which methods were called and how long they took. Using this you can trace which methods are taking the longest and hopefully reduce the overhead with your app.